# What regex replace can I use to remove everything before the 2nd space from the end of the string?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Example:
Something once upon a time

should be replaced with regex to:

a time

The rule is strip everything starting from the 2nd space from the end of the string. I'm not very familiar with regex starting anywhere other than the beginning of the string so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex:

`\S*\s\S*$`

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tCxSO7/1).

Comment: `[^\s]` is a weird way to say `\S`. Neither of these escapes are supported in many regex dialects which are not descended from Perl's.

Comment: More fundamentally, this is broken because it counts spaces from the end of the string, not from the beginning, as per OP's requirement.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my fault. As you see, my regex is not skilled. So I'm doing practices. Does this, "this is broken because it counts spaces from the end of the string, not from the beginning, as per OP's requirement.", means the question goes against the fundamental of regex? @tripleee

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question; they want to count from the end.

Comment: @tripleee It doesn't matter. At least, I remember that capital represents the set lowercase excluding. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the character class around `\S`, it's already a character class on its own.

Comment: @tripleee Tears of Joy.